# Latex pick specific element of an array of strings based on variable

Tags: latex

Here's my setup. I want to set a integer variable called intoption at the top of my latex document.

```
\newcommand{\intoption}{3} % This variable can be 1,2,3 or 4
```

I also want to define a command called pickoption that will use the intoption value, say value x, to pick the x-th element of the array. So

```
\pickoption{First}{Second}{3rd}{Last}
```

will return the text "3rd". Is this behavior possible? How would I define pickoption?

Comment: This feels like an xy-problem. Can you maybe give a bit more background what your `\pickoption` macto will be used for?

Comment: The \pickoption is to generate different versions of the document from one template document.

Comment: Which kinds of different versions? For different audiences with more or less content, for different languages? In different layout? How do you setup your template? Via a package or just a bunch of code in the preamble?

Comment: The versions share 95% the same text. Instead of maintaining separate documents, the command \pickoption is scattered in multiple places through out the document. Each instance of the \pickoption actually picks from completely different array of strings. I just need 4 versions at the moment though I can imagine more might be needed in the future. So \pickoption would work very well if its generalizable.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience instead of reinventing the wheel? (or one of the other package in the area https://www.ctan.org/topic/cond-comp)

Answer (score 1):

One of many possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\intoption}{3}


\newcommand{\pickoption}[4]{
  \ifnum\intoption=1
    #1
  \else
    \ifnum\intoption=2
      #2
    \else
      \ifnum\intoption=3
        #3
      \else
        \ifnum\intoption=4
          #4
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi    
}


\begin{document}

\pickoption{First}{Second}{3rd}{Last}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing it this way. Is there any way to extend this to arbitrary number of choices? I had specified \pickoption to take in 4 arguments as a concrete example.

Comment: @Alpha8 Not with the syntax you choose for `\pickoption`. If you want arbitrary number of options, a key value interface might be better suited than a command with a fixed number of mandatory arguments. As I said, this feels like an xy problem...